# Ambiguous Reference System.Net.Http.Formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using VS2015 .Trying to use System.Net.Http.Formatting gives me an error saying:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0433  The type 'MultipartMemoryStreamProvider' exists in both 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' aaAPIs  C:\Working\Angular\aa\Controllers\Product\ImagesController.cs   22
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try adding a binding redirect.

Comment: I have a binding redirect, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are referencing two different versions of the same DLL in your project (version 4 and version 5). I think you should try cleaning up the references and try using only one version